# $WinREAgent folder keeps to automatically appear

Tags: windows, directory, windows-10

There is an automatic $WinREAgent folder on my C: drive. Do you know if I can configure another location for this folder auto-generation? Or turn off the generation of this folder?

I tried to find some kind of configuration in the registry, without success. Neither in the Windows Update panel.

Thank you.